# Method .click() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this textarea:

```
<textarea id="updElement"></textarea>
```

And I use it with the script:

```
    document.getElementById('updElement').onchange = function () {
    var l = document.getElementsByClassName("dijitTreeRowSelected");
    l[0].click();
};
```

So when I change manually the textarea by adding some symbols, my script is running. But my problem is, that I need to run the script by calling like a function for example:

```
function changeTree(){
    var l = document.getElementsByClassName("dijitTreeRowSelected");
    l[0].click();
}
```

but it does not work. I am not using any library.

Comment: are you using jQuery or just straight up JavaScript?

Comment: @loulala: Well, there's nothing using jQuery above, and there's no jQuery tag, so...

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha).

Comment: How and when do you call this function?

Comment: what appen calling click()? are you using it for focus on textarea? or there is a listener doing something?

Comment: @loulala: It's clear from the code that it's the `click` on a DOM element.

Comment: *"I'm using a pure JavaScript and i need to resolve it using only JS."* You'd be using JavaScript whether you were using jQuery or not. jQuery isn't a language, it's a library. What you mean is that you're using the DOM, without any additonal library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the code here, it is working,

```js
  document.getElementById('updElement').onchange = function() {
    changeTree();
  };

function changeTree() {
  var l = document.getElementsByClassName("dijitTreeRowSelected");
  l[0].click();
}
```

```html
<textarea id="updElement"></textarea>
<button class="dijitTreeRowSelected" onclick="alert('element click event triggred from somewhwre')">
        Test DOM Element
        </button>
```

Test example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vesm7n45/7/